# Uncaught Error: Cannot add node "1" because a node with that id is already in the Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-debugger

```
I can't debug in react-native using the react-native debugger 

   Uncaught Error: Cannot add node "1" because a node with that id is already in the Store.
    C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:48 Uncaught Error: Cannot add node "1" because a node with that id is already in the Store.
        at C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:48
        at c.emit (C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:48)
        at C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:48
        at C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:48
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at S.Gc.e.onmessage (C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:48)
        at S.n (C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:40)
        at S.emit (events.js:315)
        at e.exports.P (C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:8)
        at e.exports.emit (events.js:315)
        at e.exports.dataMessage (C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:8)
        at e.exports.getData (C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:8)
        at e.exports.startLoop (C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:8)
        at e.exports._write (C:\Users\kbelhadjali\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.12.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js:8)
        at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403)
        at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387)
```

and when i tried to use the debugger-ui only it doesn't work aswell and showing me this error:

```
Development Tools failed to load source map: Unable to load content from http: // localhost: 19000 / debugger-ui / debuggerWorker.aca173c4.js.map: Failed to retrieve via target: Target not taken in charge ; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net :: ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

i even created a blank project to test if the problem is caused by my project but it didn't work aswell showing me the same errors.

Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem.  I discovered the react-native-debugger was opening an instance in my web-browser and a separate stand alone instance.  When I closed the instance in my web browser, the error stopped occurring and I could debug normally.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem, my dependencies:

```
...
"expo": "~43.0.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.3"
```

Seems like `"react-devtools-core"` in react-native dependencies install old package version.

I added

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react-devtools-core": "4.14.0"
  }
```

To `package.json` for solving this problem.
I also reinstall last react-native-debugger ( `brew reinstall react-native-debugger`)
Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for you response, but sadly it didn't work for me and the react-native-debugger still showing the same error.

Comment: you need to add the dependency and install the package again with npm or yarn.

Worked for me well!